# google sheets Get the last non-empty cell in a ROW

Tags: regex, google-sheets

this is the simplified version of my data.
[image]

How can I calculate E and F columns? the address format of E column is not important.

Comment: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-find-the-last-value-in-each-row-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this custom formula to E2 `=last_item_index(A2:D)`

and here is the custom function code:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function last_item_index(range) {
  const colCount = range[0].length
  const lastItemIndices = range.map(row=>{
    const indexFirstNonEmpty = row.reverse().findIndex(cell=>cell)
    const indexLastNonEmpty = colCount - 1 - indexFirstNonEmpty
    return indexFirstNonEmpty>=0? [indexLastNonEmpty, row[indexFirstNonEmpty]] : ['','']
  })
  return lastItemIndices
}
```

The value returned in column E will be the zero-based index of the last non-empty item. You can easy convert it to A1-formatted range with [ADDRESS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:D="",,
 ADDRESS(ROW(A2:A), COLUMN(A:D), 4))),,9^9))), " (.{1,3}\d+)$")))
```

[image]

and:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:D="",,
 SUBSTITUTE(A2:D, " ", "♦"))),,9^9))), "((?:[^ ]+ *){1})$"), "♦", " ")))
```

[image]